# Why can't I change the code page in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ascii, codepages

New here, so I'll try to explain my problem as best as I can.

I tried coding a program in Visual Studio C++ that reads Japanese letters from a text file and displays them. The debug console gave me weird hieroglyphic-looking symbols.

I did some research and can deduce that that's because I was using an ASCII codepage which can read and display only the most common letters, like the Western alphabet. It was something along those lines.

I changed the system locale in Control Panel > Region > Administrative > System Locale to Japanese. After this, the fonts changed and some of the text in the debug console in Visual Studio displayed differently than before. However, it still displayed errors, so I gave up and tried changing it back to the default settings, but I'm having trouble.

My main goal is to try to revert everything back. In the debug console properties, it shows that the codepage I'm using is still Japanese, even after many attempts to fix it and reset the settings to default. I want the fonts to go back to "Consolas", but that option isn't available anymore. I even tried looking in the Registry after looking up answers, but everything was in its rightful place.

Can anyone give me some assistance?

Comment: This is not a programming question.  Try asking on [su].

Comment: Ah ok thanks. I’ll do that.